# How can I create namespace in different dll file?

Tags: c#, namespaces

I write a dll file with namespace "MyLib". Now I find I need to expend the namespace "MyLib", add sub namespace like "MyLib.Query". I create a new dll project named "MyLib.Query.dll" with the namespace "MyLib.Query". But when I create test application, complier always told me "there is no type or namespace "Query" in namespace "MyLib".
Why?

Comment: What file/line is the compiler flagging with that error? Could you edit your post to contain the context?

Comment: You are probably not aware of the fact that a namespace is a logical concept, while a dll (an assembly) is a "physical" concept. You can have multiple namespaces within the same dll, or multiple dlls sharing the same namepsace. Besides, your question is not clear as it's missing critical details - mainly, what are the references your test application is using?